# Stopped compiling

Tags: compiling

I have a problem with compiling in latex. I was trying to write a matrix, when latex suddenly did not want to compile it anymore. I deleted everything new, but it still did not work. First it had some messages that had many "full box" warnings. I have had many of these before, but it was still working. Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Need a MWE which shows the problem.  I suspect you have left a { without it matching }.

Comment: Do you mean like this:Overfull \hbox (73.78595pt too wide) detected at line 280
[] [][] [][] []\OML/cmm/m/it/10 dud \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 = [][] [][] \OML/cmm/m/it/
10 d \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 = [](\OMS/cmsy/m/n/10 ] [7] [8] [9] [10]

! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.835 \documentclass
                    [reqno]{amsart}
?

Comment: when latex stops compiling partway through a job, it's always a good idea to delete any "derived" files -- `.aux`, `.toc`, etc. -- so that they don't subvert your attempt to restart after removing what you know caused a problem in the earlier try.

Comment: It would help to see the actual latex code.  From your log snippet I suspect  you have put something in the body of the code which can only be in the preamble.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an error in the user's file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 835 of your main file you have

```
\documentclass [reqno]{amsart}
```

which is the start of a file.

I would guess you accidentally cut and pasted the entire document into itself.

Comment: You were right. I am not sure how it happened, but I must have somehow copied and pasted the entire document. I therefore deleted the things copied, and it now works perfectly again. Thank you.